# Flask with python3.5.2 want to print json

Tags: python, json, flask

```
@app.route('/schedule', methods=['POST'])
def schedule():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
```

But error ouccured.
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

How to print json data ??

Comment: Do you want to print to the Flask logs, or *return a JSON response in the browser*?

Comment: And based on the error, you're not showing the correct code. `write()` isn't used, and print will happily print both strings and bytes objects

Comment: I wanted to print to flask log.

Comment: Can you please show the full error?

Comment: Sorry , Oh, I wrote the code  I removed the code and printed out.  

    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf_8')(sys.stdout)

Comment: Please [edit] your question accordingly. The shown code does not have any errors